# Cycle through different sized images on scroll

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change through images when scrolling, (and I understand that maybe the jquery is a bit messy but it seems to be working) but i would like:

- to be able to have images of different heights and widths, not all the same size (as it is now).
- vertically/horizontally centered.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/postcolonialboy/WTkqn/486/

Thanks!

HTML:

```
   <div id="contentwrapper">
      <div class="centreme">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1" id="animation" />
        <img class="hidden" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1" />
        <img class="hidden" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=2" />
        <img class="hidden" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=3" />
        <img class="hidden" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=4" />
        <img class="hidden" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=5" />
        <div id="bottommark"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body,
      html {
        height: 7000px;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: grey;
      }

      .hidden {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999999px
      }

      #bottommark {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
      }

      #contentwrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
      }

      .centreme {
        position: fixed;
        width: 200px;
        /* the image width */
        height: 200px;
        /* the image height */
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -100px;
        /* half the image height */
        margin-left: -100px;
        /* half the image width */
      }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var a = $(document).height();
        var b = a - $("#bottommark").position().top;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
          var e = $(document).height();
          var f = $(window).scrollTop();
          var c = e - $("#bottommark").position().top - f;
          var d = b / 5;
          $("span").html(c);
          if (c > d * 4) {
            $("#animation").attr("src", "https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1")
          }
          if ((c < d * 4) && (c > d * 3)) {
            $("#animation").attr("src", "https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=2")
          }
          if ((c < d * 3) && (c > d * 2)) {
            $("#animation").attr("src", "https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=3")
          }
          if (c < d * 2 && c > d * 1) {
            $("#animation").attr("src", "https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=4")
          }
          if (c < d) {
            $("#animation").attr("src", "https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=5")
          }
        })
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is much better with less code.

**now you can have as many images as you want without changing js and css part**

```js
$(function() {
 var win = $(window),
  images = $(".images > div"),
  img = $(".img > img");

 img.attr('src', images.eq(0).data('img'));

 win.on('scroll', function(event) {
  var st = win.scrollTop(),
     num1 = $(document).height() / images.length,
    num = Math.round(st / num1);

  img.attr('src', images.eq(num).data('img'));
 });
});
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 8000px;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: grey;
}

.img {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
 <div data-img="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=1"></div>
 <div data-img="https://picsum.photos/400/300?image=2"></div>
 <div data-img="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=3"></div>
 <div data-img="https://picsum.photos/300/400?image=4"></div>
 <div data-img="https://picsum.photos/500/300?image=5"></div>
</div>

<div class="img"><img></div>
```

Comment: it works very well. this is almost it! the only thing is that the height of the page is defined by an amount of text in the body. how can the images cycle according to the length of the content. see here: https://jsbin.com/rusuzol/edit?html,output

Comment: ok i have updated the answer. you just need to change num and num1 variables like this

Answer (score 0):

Should have your image centering sorted at the **[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/byokjwsz/9/)**.
**Whats changed?**
The `centreme` class has just 3 styles declared to it now, the position (fixed), width and height (100%). Then by targeting your images (in this case with an additional class `image-tag`), we can center it perfectly within it's parent by using the following declarations:

```
.image-tag {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Put simply, we are centering the child by going to the exact center of the parent and then positioning the child so that *it's* center sits on top of the parents.